# In EXCEL search two conditions and if found end the Flight Load

Tags: excel

Need formula : in CELL NO C9 in  EXCEL SHEET1

Description: SHEET1

Rows:-

```
ROW1 ie  Flight Date
ROW2 ie  Flight Nos
ROW5 ie  Economy  Class Load i.e Passenger Counts
ROW5 ie  Business Class Load i.e Passenger Counts
```

Columns :

```
"A" i.e Menu HBF : Hot Breakfast
"B" i.e Menu Cycle
```

Description: SHEET2  DATE WISE MENU against Menu Cycle Code

Requirement:  =Cell Sheet1!C9,  IF Flight DATE i.e 1 then Enter Class Load against Menu Cycle as mentioned onSheet2

Enter Class Load as per  Menu Cycle
Below mentioned Matrix is of date of Aug 2023

```
C1  7,8,15,16,23,24,31  
C2  1,2,9,10,17,18,25,26
C3  3,4,11,12,19,20,27,28
C4  5,6,13,14,21,22,29,30
```

Answer is in RED FONT

[image]

Comment: I can't follow the logic for the answers you say are in red font. It looks to me like the only "answers" that are correct are in cells `D12:D14`. It seems to me that you're trying to return the Load value when it's in the same row as its Rotation code. Is that right? Can you try to clear this up in your original post?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the answers in red are actually from a prior month and don't apply to the August table you provided in the image. If that's the case, then try pasting the following formula in `Sheet1`, cell `C8`:

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$I$5, SWITCH($B8,"c1",1,"c2",2,"c3",3,"c4",4,""),
MATCH(C$5, IFS($B8="c1", Sheet2!$B$2:$I$2, $B8="c2", Sheet2!$B$3:$I$3,$B8="c3", 
Sheet2!$B$4:$I$4, $B8="c4", Sheet2!$B$5:$I$5),0) ) 
,"")
```

From there, drag the formula to the right until you reach the last column in your range. Then drag the highlighted row down until you've reached the last row in your range.

This should work in legacy Excel and in Excel 365.

Regarding your table structure---setting up a normalized table structure can make the formula a little more straightforward.  For example:

| Rotation | Load |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | 7 |
| C1 | 8 |
| C1 | 15 |
| ... | ... |
| C2 | 1 |

In this case, you can nest just a couple of functions (`INDEX(MATCH())`) to achieve the same result.